# CodeIgniter use base_url() in helper

Tags: codeigniter

I am creating a new helper ,so that I can reuse it in views, etc .. can I use base_url() in the helper ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use base_url() in helper. 
Make sure url_helper is loaded before using base_url().

Comment: I have loaded it in the controller..should I load it in the new helper that I am gonna create also ? thanks ..

Comment: You don't need to recreate if you load url_helper before your own helper.

Comment: In fact it is a good idea to manually load any dependent helpers so if you ever publish or distribute it you can avoid having to explain to people that they need to add the url helper in the autoload portion of the config.